# Linux freezes on reboot. Requires BIOS change to windows8 from win7

Tags: bios, freeze, crash, uefi, reboot

I use an Intel celeron J1900 based Nano-itx board (http://www.qotom.net/product/17.html )  which runs ubuntu linux. When reboot command is typed on console, the system freezes after few seconds. The same behavior happens with Yocto poly linux. The solution ( https://forums.untangle.com/hardware/42112-qotom-j1900-hangs-reboot.html ) is to power cycle and boot into BIOS. Change to "OS Selection" option from Windows 7 to Windows8.x .

I am trying to solve this without power cycling the box. Is there any way to change this bios setting from inside the running linux . I have a remote box where it is difficult to send a person to power cycle. I have ssh ability to the box. Any solution that does not require physically going to box that allows clean reboot will be good.

Comment: Try __reboot=bios__ (source : https://askubuntu.com/questions/794627/dell-poweredge-t20-wont-reboot) there are many suggestions and two answers there.

Comment: thank you @vssher but none of the options are helping. Is there any way a x86 BIOS/UEFI settings can be changed from inside the running linux OS?

Comment: This may help, (ServerFault is also part of StackExchange). "Is it possible to change BIOS settings from Linux?" https://serverfault.com/questions/498557/is-it-possible-to-change-bios-settings-from-linux